# Changing the Location of Global Packages

Tags: npm, npm-install

Bash doesn't use new location of npm.

I am following this guide on changing the location of Global Packages and got stuck.
https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/

I've ran this command
    `npm config set prefix=$HOME/.node_modules_global`

and the prefix has changed

Then I need to

> add `.node_modules_global/bin` to our $PATH environment variable, so that we can run global packages from the command line. Do this by appending the 
>   following line to your .profile, .bash_profileor .bashrc and restarting 
>   your terminal.
>
> `export PATH="$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH"`

I have located .profile, added this line, but `which npm` still shows old location - `/usr/local/bin/npm`

Comment: Same thin for me! Does not seem to work. Did you find the solution?